# From where these ghost-pixels are taken?

Tags: html, css

I have input, and main info it has these two properties:

```
    #answer_user_answer{

    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: solid 1px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

But, when I view it actual width with Chrome developer tool, it is 112px.

100+5+5=110, what is two additional pixels?

(I'm asking, coz these form on submit should be replaced with element with exactly same width, not to cause other element shift, and I don't want to write special JS function for that. How do I know, that other browsers don't insert 4,6 additional pixels?).

Comment: There may be other containers that are affecting the width, without more information we cannot know

Comment: now I got idea that it is border-width...it is 1px. It makes sense

Comment: Are you using [css reset](http://www.cssreset.com/)?

Comment: width+padding+border+margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra two pixels are the border.

This can be a problem for working out how wide an element can be and how much space is left over, etc.

There is an option to switch the box model such that the border and padding are included inside the box, which can help with this:

If you specify `box-sizing:border-box;` in your CSS for the element, then the total width of your element will be exactly 100 pixels; the border and padding will be pushed *inside* the fixed width and will take up space inside the box rather than adding size to the element outside of it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I think box-sizing is best way to set width to exactly what you need

Comment: Make sure you set it on *all* elements that affect each other in a group, otherwise it can get *really* confusing! Also please note that it isn't supported in IE6/IE7. Hopefully you don't need to support those old browsers, but if you do, you'll need to use a polyfill to do it.

Comment: Do note that border-box sizing for some browsers either requires a vendor prefix, or doesn't work. Details here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-sizing` property.

```
#answer_user_answer {
    ...
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ...
}
```

The default value of `box -sizing` is `content-box`. In case of `content-box`, any `padding` and `border` you give to element adds to its width. So

```
100px + 5px + 5px + 1px + 1px
-----   ---------   ---------     gives 112px
width    padding      border
```

Comment: it will includes padding as well :)

Comment: +1. I also figured this was what the OP was really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's due to a `border`. Without posting anymore code it's hard to figure out.

Like Vucko suggested, you should consider a [CSS reset](https://code.google.com/p/html5resetcss/downloads/list) file.

If you inspect the code either with Chrome or Firefox after applying the reset CSS file, you should note some differences.